# What's the dispel DC for a spell made permanent by another caster?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, caster-level

I am level 9 and I cast an Enlarge Person spell on myself.

An NPC is level 16 and casts Permanency on that Enlarge Person effect to make me larger permanently.

When an enemy later attempts to dispel the Enlarge Person effect, does the enemy roll against the caster level of me as the caster of Enlarge Person or the NPC's as the caster of Permanency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the *dispel magic* spell's caster attempts to dispel the question's [*enlarge person*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enlarge-person/) spell, the caster makes a caster level check (DC 20; i.e. DC = 11 + the caster level of the *enlarge person* spell). If the caster succeeds, the *dispel magic* spell dispels the target's *enlarge person* spell. If the caster fails, the *enlarge person* spell remains. To be clear, this occurs whether or not a [*permanency*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency/) spell has been applied to the *enlarge person* spell; the *permanency* spell is a non-issue here.

All the spell *permanency* does is **change** a spell's [duration](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Magic/#Duration) from its printed duration to permanent (therefore the spell continues forevermore until dispelled or suppressed). That is, while the *permanency* spell has the entry *Duration: Permanent; see text*, the text that should be seen is this: "This spell makes the duration of certain other spells permanent. You first cast the desired spell and then follow it with the *permanency* spell."

Thus the caster of a *dispel magic* spell can affect a spell **modified** by a *permanency* spell but can't affect the *permanency* spell itself. (This gives the actual *permanency* spell essentially a duration that's sort of instantaneous—one casting of the spell *permanency* changes forevermore the duration of that specific casting of the target spell until that specific casting of that spell is dispelled.)

So it usually doesn't matter at what caster level the *permanency* spell is cast. (See below for a noteworthy exception.) The spell *permanency* still requires a minimum caster level to target some spells, of course, but nothing remains of a *permanency* spell **after** it's cast. It did its job by changing the target spell's duration, and now to get rid of the spell the changed spell must be dispelled. There simply is no ongoing *permanency* spell to be dispelled separately.

Typically, the only thing that alters the difficulty of dispelling a spell affected by the *permanency* spell even a little is if a caster casts *permanency* on a spell he cast on himself that's also on the chart that's labeled *Target: Self Only* in the *permanency* spell description. In that case, not only must the *dispel magic* spell's caster succeed on a caster level check (DC = 11 + caster level of the changed spell) but also the spell changed by the *permanency* spell "can be dispelled only by a caster of higher level than you were when you cast the spell." (N.b. Here *the spell* means *the spell on the Target: Self Only list* and, again, not the *permanency* spell!)

In other words, a caster can cast on himself a spell from the chart Target: Self Only and make it permanent on himself with the *permanency* spell and know that only a caster that possesses a higher level than he was when he cast the spell on the chart can dispel that spell. (Here *higher level* probably means *high caster level*, but ask the GM.) By the way, sadly absent from the Target: Self Only chart is the spell *enlarge person*.

Answer (score 3):

## Foreword

I think that @HeyICanChan's response is a perfectly reasonable RAI interpretation of *[permanency](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/permanency/)*, and I would have no complaint about a GM using it in a game in which I played. However, I think that, RAW, the spell functions a little differently...

## Text of the Spell

The *permanency* spell reads as follows. I've highlighted the sections that are particularly important to my understanding of how it works:

> School universal; Level sorcerer/wizard 5; Domain [subdomain] Magic
>   [rites] 5
>
> CASTING
>
> Casting Time 2 rounds
>   Components V, S, M (see tables below)
>
> EFFECT
>
> Range see text
>
> Target see text
>
> Duration **permanent; see text**
>
> Saving Throw none; Spell Resistance no
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> This spell makes the duration of certain other spells permanent. **You
>   first cast the desired spell and then follow it with the *permanency*
>   spell.**
>
> Depending on the spell, you must be of a minimum caster level and must
>   expend a specific gp value of diamond dust as a material component.
>
> You can make the following spells permanent in regard to yourself. You
>   cannot cast these spells on other creatures. **This application of
>   *permanency* can be dispelled only by a caster of higher level than you
>   were when you cast the spell.**
>
> ...
>
> In addition to personal use, *permanency* can be used to make the following spells permanent on yourself, another creature, or an object (as appropriate):
>
> ...
>
> Additionally, the following spells can be cast upon objects or areas only and rendered permanent:
>
> ...
>
> **Spells cast on other targets are vulnerable to dispel magic as normal**. The GM may allow other spells to be made permanent.

From the text, it seems clear that *permanency* is intended to work differently depending on whether it's cast on one of the personal-only spells or on one of the other spells. We need to consider both cases.

## Personal-Only

### What The Rules Say

The phrasing of **"This application of *permanency* can be dispelled only by a caster of higher level than you were when you cast the spell"** seems to indicate that it's the *permanency* spell being dispelled here. That's consistent with the spell's duration being "permanent" instead of "instantaneous":

> **Instantaneous**: The spell energy comes and goes the instant the spell is cast, though
>   the consequences might be long-lasting.
>
> **Permanent**: The energy remains as long as the effect does. This means the spell is
>   vulnerable to *dispel magic*.

*Permanency* has a duration of "permanent", which indicates that the spell's magic continues working indefinitely. This is similar to spells like *baleful polymorph*, which doesn't wear off on its own but can be dispelled. If the subject of *baleful polymorph* walks into an *anti-magic field*, they revert to their normal shape while they're inside.

On the other hand, a spell like *feeblemind* has a duration of "instantaneous" - it does its damage and then the spell dissipates. The effects of *feeblemind* can only be removed by specific spells like *heal* and *limited wish*. *Dispel magic* has no effect because nothing stays around to dispel, and a feebleminded person who walks into an *anti-magic field* is still feebleminded while inside.

This all suggests that if you scan a person with *permanent see invisibility*, you see two magical auras - one for *see invisibility* and one for *permanency*. This, in turn, suggests that since *dispel magic* removes a single spell, it can potentially remove either *see invisibility* or *permanency*.

### What Does Dispelling *Permanency* Mean?

The spell doesn't explain what dispelling *permanency* means, but two reasonable interpretations are:

1. When *permanency* is cast, the target spell's normal duration is paused. When *permanency* is dispelled, the target spell continues for whatever is left of its normal duration.
2. Time under *permanency* counts against the spell's duration normally, just like when a spell is suppressed by *anti-magic field*. Usually, the target spell will already have exceeded its duration and will end immediately.

### Dispelling the Target Spell

What if the spell targeted with *permanency* is dispelled? Again, the text doesn't specify, but I can think of two possible interpretations:

1. With its target gone, the *permanency* spell vanishes. This is how I would usually rule it.
2. The *permanency* spell no longer has any effect, but it still exists and could support another casting of the same spell (since the cost of *permanency* varies by spell, it wouldn't support the casting of any spell that can be made permanent). This would allow the caster to restore the permanency of the spell without spending the cost again. I might use this interpretation in a low-money game to avoid screwing a PC, or when an evil wizard escapes and comes back for revenge.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether the couple of published NPCs who have spells affected by permanency support this answer or not, but here's [one](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/npc-s/npcs-cr-13/number-mage/) and here's [another](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/npc-s/npcs-cr-13/elali-lich-cr-13/) in case you're interested.